# Touch up inside on a Bar Button Item

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

All,

I have a Bar Button Item which will move to a different `ViewController`, and also I want it to accept a touchup inside, so that I can save settings when the user changes to another `ViewController`. but I cannot find the Touchup inside setting. I can create an `IBOutlet` on the Sent Actions but this doesn't trigger the function when i try. 
here is a screen shot
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: bar button item with button inside]

You must put the button inside bar button item. This button will contain all you looking for.

Comment: ok, you need to put a button in the bar button item, understood! but how do i add it ?

Comment: Just drag and drop uibutton to navigation bar or navigation item.

Answer (score 1):

`UIBarButtonItem` don't use `touchUpInside` event.

It only do the target and action to define when they are activated.

**Solution** : If you want the event then  **Custom** `UIBarButtonItem` from the `UIButton`.

Ex :

```
UIButton *customBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
backButton.frame =// Frame 
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(customBtnTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: customBtn];
```